# Need help on translation from UA to GA4 using Data API, not using client library

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am almost done with recoding our site to use GA4 instead of UA.  I have pulled our SEO data, but I am having an issue with our Ad data. It doesn't seem that the data can be pulled the same way.

The call to UA for our Ad data had these:

```
dimensions=ga:keyword,ga:date,ga:adGroup,ga:campaign
metrics=ga:impressions,ga:adClicks,ga:goalCompletionsAll,ga:adCost,ga:CPC
filters=ga:medium==cpc,ga:source==google
max-results=50000
```

So for GA4, I have this JSON which successfully pulls data:

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    {
        "name": "googleAdsKeyword"
    },
    {
        "name": "date"
    },
    {
        "name": "googleAdsCampaignName"
    }
  ],
  "metrics": [
    {
        "name": "advertiserAdImpressions"
    },
    {
        "name": "advertiserAdClicks"
    },
    {
        "name": "advertiserAdCostPerClick"
    },
    {
        "name": "advertiserAdCost"
    }
  ],
  "dateRanges": [
    {
        "startDate": "2023-06-01",
        "endDate": "2023-06-20"
    }
  ]
}
```

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to add filter. I cannot find any examples (shocking, I know) of the syntax for a simple filter.

I have tried to add both 'medium' and 'source' as a dimension, but both are 'not compatible', so maybe I can't filter?

But I would love to learn the syntax for a filter, so if you have any examples of JSON sent to the API with a filter I would love to see it.  For example, how would I filter for googleAdsCampaignName = 'Clearwater'

Thanks,
Kathryn